# Parsing a Matrix from a File in Go

Tags: go

I'm having a file with the following contents:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  0  0  0  7
 8  0  0  0  9
10  0  0  0 11
12 13 14 15 16
```

What I want is an multidimensional array (or slice) of `[][]int`. I tried to fiddle around with the `scanner.Scanner` library:

```
scan.Init(f) // f is a file
scan.Whitespace = 1<<'\t' | 1<<'\r' | 1<<' '
tok := scan.Scan()
for tok != scanner.EOF {
    // do something with tok
    if tok == scanner.String {
        fmt.Print("\n")
    } else if tok == scanner.Int {
        // Handle int value
        // How do I get the matched token value?
    }       

    tok = scan.Scan()
}
```

I can't find a way to get the value of the token that was matched.

So two questions:

1. How do I get the value of any scanned token?
2. How can I dynamically create that two-dimensional slice/array before knowing it's exact size? (can be any size really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the scanner package (which is suited to parse context free grammars, similar to the Go language) for such a simple task of reading numbers from a file. I would either use:

- a simple loop and [fmt.Fscan](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscan), or
- [ioutil.ReadFile](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile), [strings.Split](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) and [strconv.Atoi](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi)

> How can I dynamically create that two-dimensional slice/array before knowing it's exact size? (can be any size really)

You can't. Either read the file twice to know the exact size on your 2nd pass, or just use [append](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) to dynamically resize the underlying array of the slice. Calling `append()` multiple times also results in an amortized O(n) behavior, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1: [Scanner.TokenText](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/#Scanner.TokenText)

Ad 2.: Briefly - if the dims are to be inferred from the text representation, inner cycle: Append to a line slice (say []int) until line break -> num of mx cols. Outer cycle: Append those line slices (to a [][]int) until EOF -> num of mx rows.